# statement after a method call gets executed before call ends swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to call a method which is in another class and use a variable of that class which is getting updated in the method, after the method call. But I am getting a nil value for the variable as the statement is getting called before the method executes completely.

for example: I have two classes A and B. B has a method update and a variable updated.

```
class A {
    let obj_b = B()

    func call() {
        obj_b.update()
        let updated = obj_b.updated
    }
}

class B {
    var updated: Int?

    func updated() {
        updated = 1
    }
}
```

what I am trying is much more complex than the example and the method takes about 5secs to execute completely. Is there any way other than returning the variable that I need.

Comment: _what I am trying is much more complex than the example_ - then post the real code, because there's nothing wrong with this generic example. It probably has something to do with asynchronous execution of the method you're calling, but we won't know until you post the actual code.

Comment: Probably the OP is trying to return a value from an async call, it will be nil if the async block hasnt finished running

Comment: so how can I make it wait till the async call finishes running.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
        let obj_b = B()

        func call() {
            let updated = obj_b.updatedVariable
            print("\(updated!)")
        }
    }

    class B {
        var updatedVariable: Int?{
            return  1
        }
    }
```

While calling A

```
let obj_b = A()
obj_b.call()
```

Result Prints 1 , this is what you want the variable. You can use computed variable in such case.